# It's possible to write neural network for different size of training data inputs and outputs

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence

It's possible to write neural network for different size of training data inputs and outputs

for example:
inputs are  1. (1,2,3,4) ,  2. (2,3,1),  3. (1,2,3,4,5) and so on...
and the same for outputs 1.  (0,0,1,1)  2. (1,1,1)  3. (0,0,1,1,1)

So far I have managed to write the one which only works with the same size of training data which mean that all my training data needs to have the same length.

So far I'm stuck with this

```
NeuralNetwork net;
int[] layers = new int[3] 
{ 
    3/*Always the same*/, 
    1/*Always the same*/, 
    3 /*Always the same*/
};

string[] activation = new string[2] { "leakyrelu", "leakyrelu" };

net = new NeuralNetwork(layers, activation);
```

What I need

```
NeuralNetwork net1;
int[] layers1 = new int[3] 
{ 
    input.Length /*Based on input's Length*/, 
    1/*Always the same*/, 
    output.Length /*Based on output's Length*/
};

string[] activation1 = new string[2] { "leakyrelu", "leakyrelu" };

net = new NeuralNetwork(layers, activation);
```

```
// BackPropagate
public void BackPropagate(float[] inputs, float[] expected)
{
    float[] output = FeedForward(inputs);

    cost = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++) cost += (float)Math.Pow(output[i] - expected[i], 2);
    cost = cost / 2;

    float[][] gamma;

    List<float[]> gammaList = new List<float[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < layers.Length; i++)
    {
        gammaList.Add(new float[layers[i]]);
    }
    gamma = gammaList.ToArray();

    int layer = layers.Length - 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++) 
        gamma[layers.Length-1][i] = (output[i] - expected[i]) * activateDer(output[i],layer);

    for (int i = 0; i < neurons[layers.Length - 1].Length; i++)
    {
        biases[layers.Length - 1][i] -= gamma[layers.Length - 1][i] * learningRate;

        for (int j = 0; j < neurons[layers.Length - 2].Length; j++)
        {
            weights[layers.Length - 2][i][j] -= gamma[layers.Length - 1][i] * neurons[layers.Length-2][j] * learningRate; 
        }
    }

    for (int i = layers.Length - 2; i > 0; i--)
    {
        layer = i - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < neurons[i].Length; j++)
        {
            gamma[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < gamma[i+1].Length; k++)
            {
                gamma[i][j] = gamma[i + 1][k] * weights[i][k][j];
            }
            gamma[i][j] *= activateDer(neurons[i][j],layer);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < neurons[i].Length; j++)
        {
            biases[i][j] -= gamma[i][j] * learningRate;
            for (int k = 0; k < neurons[i-1].Length; k++)
            {
                weights[i - 1][j][k] -= gamma[i][j] * neurons[i-1][k] * learningRate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop, take a breath and think math, not code. What should the network look like?